# C++ Concurrency in Action joining_thread implementation in listing 2.7

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I am reading the second edition of C++ Concurrency in Action book and I have a question concerning chapter 2. In listing 2.7, a joining_thread class is provided. I was wondering why the second constructor copies pass the thread argument by value?

I understand that it is meant to call it like:

```
joining_thread jt{std::thread(fct)};
```

which I understand. But what prevents us from doing:

```
std::thread t(fct);
joining_thread jt(t);
```

which copies the thread to the constructor parameter and moves the copy. This seems to do differently as in listing one, where the thread guard is supposed to protect the thread passed to it, not a copy; so I guess the intention is the same here. Maybe this is not the case and I have my answer but I want to be sure to understand it correctly. Is it deliberate to create an internal copy in that case? Or what am I not understanding?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you write about copying of threads, I suppose you meant:

```
std::thread t(fct);
joining_thread jt(t);
```

instead of:

```
std::thread t(fct);
joining_thread jt(fct);
```

The first one simply does not compile because threads are non-copyable. In particular, `std::thread` has a deleted copy constructor: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/EG41WK4bx

You need to employ the move constructor here by either:

```
std::thread t(fct);
joining_thread jt(std::move(t));
```

or your original:

```
joining_thread jt{std::thread(fct)};
```

Note that you cannot write directly:

```
joining_thread jt{fct};
```

since the corresponding converting constructor of `std::thread` is `explicit`.

Comment: Yes, that was an error from my side. Thank you.